# Cannot read property 'findElement' of undefined

Tags: protractor

I am trying make protractor working for non angular site and I am having trouble when trying to read attribute for nested webelement but it keeps returning an error. Not sure why. Any idea?

html look like this
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kv2G.png)

test script:

```
browser.driver.findElements(by.css('.row')).then(function(elem){
            elem[1].findElements(by.css('.col-4.col-12-sm')).then(function (elems) {
                console.log(elems.length);
                for(i=0; i<=elems.length; i++){
                    elems[i].findElement(by.tagName('a')).getAttribute("data-post-id").then(function(attr){
                        console.log(attr);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

error:

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'findElement' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'findElement' of undefined
        at /Users/skabir/Documents/protractor-room5/test/homepage.js:17:29
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("displaying first element") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:86:14)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/skabir/Documents/protractor-room5/test/homepage.js:12:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/skabir/Documents/protractor-room5/test/homepage.js:1:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Comment: Try this, replace *elems[i].findElement(by.tagName('a'))* with *elems[i].element(by.tagName('a'));*. if it doesn't work show me *console.log(elems);*

Comment: replace `i<=elems.length` to `i<elems.length` in the for-loop.

Comment: I tried with elems[i].element(by.tagName('a')) but did not work. but its giving me type error.

TypeError: elems[i].element is not a function
        at /Users/skabir/Documents/protractor-room5/test/homepage.js:17:30
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the for loop incorrectly. element's index goes from `0 to length-1`. You have the loop index running from `0 to length` and thats the reason why you might be seeing call of a undefined element

As a side-note on the best practices .. 1. why are you writing a promise inside promise. You are just supposed to chain the. You are creating callback hell kind of scenario.   2. Use for-each instead of a for loop

May be something like below should work

```
browser.driver.findElements(by.css('.row')).then(function(elem){
    return elem[1].findElements(by.css('.col-4.col-12-sm'))
}).then(function (elems) {
    elems.forEach(function(element) {
        elems[i].findElement(by.tagName('a')).getAttribute("data-post-id").then(function(attr){
            console.log(attr);
        });
    });
});
```

And one more Important point .. Looks like you are incorrectly identifying the tag -a. The css `.col-4.col-12-sm` is not a child element of css `.row` and that could also be a reason of your unidentified. Its always important to identify best locator strategy before actually starting coding.You can just do this and keep things simple.

```
browser.driver.findElements(by.css('.col-4.col-12-sm a')).then(function(elems){
    elems.forEach(function(element) {
        element.getAttribute("data-post-id").then(function(attr){
            console.log(attr);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let cols = $$('.row').get(1).$$('.col-4.col-12-sm')
cols.count().then(console.log)
cols.each((col, index)=> {
    col.$('a').getAttribute('data-post-id').then(console.log)
})
```

Better to not call webdriverJS wrapped functions, and stay with protractorjs api.

Comment: Hey, since this is a non angular site, I am not sure if protractorjs api will work here. Thats why I am following webdriverJS.

Comment: It will work fine, you just need to set ignoreSynchronization(true) in your code before.